# SqlCommand C# Issue

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

The below piece of code that throws the following exception..

Error Message:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Stack Trace:
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I am lost as to the reason why..

```
sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strSqlconnection);

SqlCommand sqlcomSMCheckin = new SqlCommand("prc_CheckIn", sqlcon);

sqlcomSMCheckin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlcomSMCheckin.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "My App";

sqlcomSMCheckin.CommandTimeout = this.iCommandTimeOut;

if (sqlcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   sqlcon.Open();
}

if (sqlcomSMCheckin != null)
{
    sqlcomSMCheckin.ExecuteNonQuery(); // error here
    sqlcomSMCheckin.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: And you're 100% sure you're connecting to the right database? What's your connection string look like? Have you tried specifying "dbo.prc_CheckIn"  ??

Comment: yup the sp is running every 20 secs, i don't get this error during other times.

Comment: Then what has changed since those "other times" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is sqlCon a class level variable, do you have issues with the same method being called multiple times?  Is there anything static in the class?  Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: This was it. Wrapping it in using definitely helped, but dumb me missed something so obvious. Thanks ck for pointing it out.. Ran the process all weekend did not get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what's going on here - but can you try this snippet of code?

```
using(sqlcon = new SqlConnection(strSqlconnection))
{
   using(SqlCommand sqlcomSMCheckin = new SqlCommand("dbo.prc_CheckIn", sqlcon))
   {
       sqlcomSMCheckin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       sqlcomSMCheckin.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            .Value = "My App";

       sqlcomSMCheckin.CommandTimeout = this.iCommandTimeOut;

       sqlcon.Open();
       sqlcomSMCheckin.ExecuteNonQuery();
       sqlcon.Close();
   }
}
```

I replace "prc_CheckIn" with "dbo.prc_CheckIn", I specify a max length on the VARCHAR parameter (adjust as needed), wrapped everything in using {} blocks - that's about it.

Do you still get the same error??

Marc

Comment: yup. Made all the changes mentioned and am still getting the error. added the database qualification also for the sp. So it is abc.dbo.prc_CheckIn now. The code runs every 20 secs and it runs fine for several minutes and then all of a sudden i get this. I should mention that the method this code is in is used by multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

HI

The code seems OK (I recommend that you use the using clause as demonstrated to you in a previous answrer). I wonder if the problem is notfrom within the stored procedure. Try to debug it, or at least add some log recording atthe begining and end of your stored procedure to make sure that it exits OK every time.

Comment: This is a good idea - remember, the error you see is sometimes the result of a deeper error that has bubbled up to the point where it gets reported.  In this case, since the code usually works, you should look at external (database) influences.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sproc "prc_CheckIn" exist in the SQL Server you are connecting to.  Maybe it's misspelled and or not accessible to the user in the connection.

Comment: prc_ChecIn exists. This piece of code runs fine without issue except that occasionally I get this error

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** close your sqlconnection immediately after executing the sqlcommand

If this is not part of a function, then reinstating it with new is not necessary - just opening it will be sufficient.

Comment: the connection is closed immediately afterwards the code snippet just didnt include it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling connection pooling and/or multiple active result sets? I forget the connection string option for that but if you invoke the connection string builder it should be on the advanced property grid. Or on www.connectionstrings.com.

Also, is this a "user instance" database like when you add a .mdf file to a Visual Studio project using SQL Express?